# Running Week on Fiscal Calendar

Tags: t-sql

I have a problem on this calendar, the weeks calculations per year are working correctly based on our needs, but now I need to add a iteration variable (***@runningWeekSeed***) that increments in 1 when the week changes (***@WorkWeekSeed***).
I'm not sure If i explained correctly.

```
/*
This Query is built for a 4-4-5 calendar, Mon - Sun week.
Each Fiscal year start on 01/01/YYYY ends on 12/31/YYYY.
*/
DECLARE 
        @FiscalCalendarStart DATETIME,                              -- Calendar starts
    @EndOfCalendar DATETIME,                                    -- Calendar ends
    @CurrentDate DATETIME,                                      -- Calendar date being calculated against

    @RunningDaySeed INT,                                        -- Days calculations
    @RunningWeekSeed INT,                                       -- Weeks calculations
    @FiscalYearSeed INT,                                        -- Years calculations

    @RunningPeriodSeed INT,                                     -- Fiscal Month
    @WorkWeekSeed INT,                                          -- Fiscal Week
    @WorkQuarterSeed INT,                                       -- Fiscal Quarter            

    @WorkPeriod INT,                                                -- Used to assign where the extra "leap week" goes. Based on the 4-4-5 calendar.
    @WeekEnding DATETIME



DECLARE @FiscalTimePeriods AS TABLE (
                                    Sysdate VARCHAR (10),           -- Date with format MMDDYYYY
                                    Date_Time_Target DATETIME,      -- The date, but with Time duh
                                    MSC_Week INT,                   -- Running week according MSC Calendar
                                    MSC_Year INT,                   -- Calendar with corresponding days into the Fiscal year
                                    weekEnding DATETIME,
                                    runningWeekSeed INT

                                )--Of Table

/*  These are user variables, and should be set according every need        */       
SELECT
    @FiscalCalendarStart = '20150101',                          -- The date of year start. Used as the base date for calculations (This case will be on 12/29/2015 to match 7 days week for week 1 of 2015)
    @EndOfCalendar = '20901231' ,                               -- The date on which the calendar query will end. Can be adjusted for each need
    @RunningDaySeed = 1,                                        -- This is used to measure the number of days since the calendar began, often used for depreciation (usually 1)
    @RunningPeriodSeed = 1,                                     -- The number of fiscal months since the original calendar began (usually 1)
    @RunningWeekSeed = 1,                                       -- The number of fiscal weeks since the original calendar began (usually 1)
    @FiscalYearSeed = 2015                                      -- The starting fiscal year (first 3 days of week 1 belongs to 2014 but it's on 2015 fiscal calendar)

/*  These are iteration variables, do not mess with these       */
SELECT       
    @WorkPeriod = 1 ,
    @WorkWeekSeed = 1 ,
    @WorkQuarterSeed = 1

/*  The loop is iterated once for each day                      */
SET @CurrentDate = @FiscalCalendarStart
SELECT @WeekEnding =  dateadd ( D , 8 - DATEPART ( DW , @CurrentDate ), @CurrentDate )

WHILE @CurrentDate <= @EndOfCalendar

BEGIN --MAIN BEGIN

   INSERT INTO @FiscalTimePeriods
   SELECT
        CONVERT ( VARCHAR (10), @CurrentDate , 101 ) AS SysDate,
        @CurrentDate AS Date_Time_Target,
        @WorkWeekSeed AS MSC_Week,
        YEAR (@CurrentDate) AS MSC_Year,
        @WeekEnding,
        @RunningWeekSeed



                                                        /*  Iterate the date and increment the RunningDay   */
   SET @CurrentDate = DATEADD ( D , 1 , @CurrentDate )
   SELECT   @RunningDaySeed = @RunningDaySeed + 1,
            @WeekEnding =  dateadd ( D , 8 - DATEPART ( DW , @CurrentDate ), @CurrentDate )

                                                        /* If @CurrentDate is 01/01/YYYY, reset fiscal counters  */
        IF (DATEPART (MONTH, @CurrentDate) = 1 AND DATEPART(DAY, @CurrentDate) = 1)
            BEGIN   
                    SELECT
                            @WorkPeriod = 1 ,
                            @WorkWeekSeed = 1 ,
                            @WorkQuarterSeed = 1,
                            @FiscalYearSeed = @FiscalYearSeed + 1
            END

        ELSE
                                                        /*************Check if Monday is between 12/23 to 12/31 *****************/
        IF DATEPART ( DW , @CurrentDate ) = 2               -- Check if @CurrentDate is monday
            IF DATEPART (MONTH, @CurrentDate) = 12 AND  (DATEPART(DAY, @CurrentDate) in (23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31)) -- If @CurrentDate is Dec 23 to 31
            BEGIN
                    SELECT
                        @WeekEnding =  dateadd ( D , 8 - DATEPART ( DW , @CurrentDate ), @CurrentDate ),
                        @WorkWeekSeed = 52,
                        @WorkQuarterSeed = 4,
                        @WorkPeriod = 12
            END

        ELSE

        IF DATEPART ( DW , @CurrentDate ) = 2
            BEGIN
                SELECT
                    @WeekEnding =  dateadd ( D , 8 - DATEPART ( DW , @CurrentDate ), @CurrentDate ),
                    @WorkWeekSeed       = CASE
                                                WHEN @WorkWeekSeed = 53 THEN 52
                                                ELSE @WorkWeekSeed + 1
                                            END
            END
        /* Compare if current date acomplish ISO_WEEK standard ISO 8601*/
        IF DATEPART ( ISO_WEEK , @CurrentDate ) = 1
                             SELECT 
                                    @WorkPeriod = 1,
                                    @WorkWeekSeed = 1,
                                    @WorkQuarterSeed = 1

            ------------------------HERE IS WHERE START TO DO THE CALCULATION OF THE runningWeekSeed-------------------------


        IF @WorkWeekSeed = 52
                SELECT  @WeekEnding =  dateadd ( D , 8 - DATEPART ( DW , @CurrentDate ), @CurrentDate ),
                        @RunningWeekSeed = @RunningWeekSeed
        ELSE

        IF DATEPART(DW, @CurrentDate) = 2

                SELECT @RunningWeekSeed = @RunningWeekSeed + 1
        ELSE
            IF (DATEPART (MONTH, @CurrentDate) = 1 AND DATEPART(DAY, @CurrentDate) = 1)

                SELECT @RunningWeekSeed = @RunningWeekSeed + 1


END -- MAIN BEGIN


SELECT

* 
FROM @FiscalTimePeriods

ORDER BY Date_Time_Target ASC
```

The needed results need to be like this

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of new posting here, but I already added the question

Comment: Why aren't your weeks all the same length? One is 7 days, one is 11, on is 10? I get the feeling there's an easier way to do what you're trying to do, but I don't think I understand what that is.

Comment: That's the way it's built
Fiscal Calendar it's build like this
Year start on 01/01/YYY and ends on 12/31YYYY

Week 1 should accomplish ISO_WEEK, that mean 4 days minimum, else the days left will be added on next week
after week 1 it's done, all the weeks following are 7 days long starting on Monday and ending on Sunday.
Week 52 have the rest of the days of the calendar
I'm not sure if that explain that, on the image is not very clear because it's on a excel.
WorkWeekSeed works just fine, the one I'm triying to make it's the runningWeekSeed

Comment: From week 2 to 51 they work perfect, they are 7 days lenght M-S, the problem is week 1 and 52